# How to place an image alongside a div

Tags: css

I have a div with a border as such:

[image]

The style used for the div representing the contents above is as such:

```
const style = {
            textAlign: "center",
            marginLeft: "20%",
            marginRight: "40%",
            border: "1px solid grey",
            borderRadius: "15px",
            marginBottom: "2%"
};
```

the variable above is used as the style for the div.

```
<div className="ExerciseType" style={style}>
            <h3>{this.props.routine.exercise.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.props.routine.exercise.slice(1)}</h3>
            <div>
                {exerciseType}
            </div>
            <img src={determineImage(this.props.routine.exercise)} alt=""
                 data-tip={this.props.routine.exercise}/>
</div>
```

The image is displayed under the bulleted components, however, I am attempting to have it shown on the right of the bulleted text.

Looking around, it seemed as if the answer would be to set a style to the div containing `{exerciseType}` to float to the left and the image to float to the right.

This, however, completely distorts the borders with the image and text leaking out and not conforming to its actual boundaries.

How then, would I go about adding a style or reformatting the components to have the bullets and image side-by-side and the border encompassing them wholly?

Comment: To prevent destroying the parent elements-border you have to set to the parent the float:left  style too.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the float, either with a clearfix or with overflow hidden on the parent.

In this example I have used a clearfix.

Also note that the image needs to go above the rest of the content for the float to work.

Clearfix: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ypod85oz/1/

**CSS**

```
.ExerciseType {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.ExerciseType:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
img {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
* {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a flex in main div and flex-direction will be row. Take another div inside the main div for displaying image. [Here the link which may help you...](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)